# Animation - GIF

Tags: android, animation

Can someone please give the Code and XML file required to create an animation using .png files?
I've tried the one given in here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

But, once I type,

```
<animation-list android:id="selected" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/connected01" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/connected02" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/connected03" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/connected04" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/connected05" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

I'm getting an error : "unbound prefix"

Can someone say how this could be done ?

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to first item of your xml

Comment: yeah! I got it today! Thanks a lot :)