# error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: java, android, xml, bluetooth

I have gotten this error in the strings.xml file: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

```
<resources>
    <string name="mainTitle">Remote Doctor </string>
    <string name="app_name">Remote Doctor</string>
    <string name="patientButton">Patient Mode </string>
    <string name="doctorButton">Doctor Mode </string>
    <string name="aboutButton">About </string>
    <string name="exit">Exit</string>
    <string name="simpleMode">Simple Mode</string>
    <string name="detailedMode">Detailed Mode</string>
    <string name="aboutTitle">About Remote Doc</string>
    <string name="aboutText">\
    Remote Doc is an application that allows a brace user and the doctor to analyze and record  
    how often the brace is being worn and how much force or pressure the brace is putting on 
    the user       </string> 

    <!--  BluetoothChat -->    
    <string name="send">Send</string>    
    <string name="not_connected">You are not connected to a device</string>    
Error:  <string name="bt_not_enabled_leaving">Bluetooth was not enabled. Leaving Bluetooth Chat.</string>    
    <string name="title_connecting">connecting...</string>    
    <string name="title_connected_to">connected to <xliff:g id="device_name">%1$s</xliff:g></string>    
    <string name="title_not_connected">not connected</string>    
    <!--  DeviceListActivity -->    
    <string name="scanning">scanning for devices...</string>    
    <string name="select_device">select a device to connect</string>    
    <string name="none_paired">No devices have been paired</string>    
    <string name="none_found">No devices found</string>    
    <string name="title_paired_devices">Paired Devices</string>    
    <string name="title_other_devices">Other Available Devices</string>    
    <string name="button_scan">Scan for devices</string>    
    <!-- Options Menu -->    
    <string name="secure_connect">Connect a device - Secure</string>    
    <string name="insecure_connect">Connect a device - Insecure</string>    
    <string name="discoverable">Make discoverable</string>   
</resources>
```

What Am i doing something wrong???

Comment: Yes, not sure what, but the answer would be yes.

Comment: Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have an XML namespace defined for `<xliff:g id="device_name">%1$s</xliff:g>`

In reality you're going to want to escape the `< >` around the `xliff:g` tags.  The text inside the `<string>` tags is being handled as raw XML instead of as part of the string value.

Use this instead for the title_connected_to entry:

`<string name="title_connected_to">connected to &lt;xliff:g id="device_name"&gt;%1$s&lt;/xliff:g&gt;<string>`

Comment: device_name is defined in a seprate xml file

Comment: device_name.xml:  <?xml version="1.0" 
encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 android:layout_width="match_parent"    
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
 android:textSize="18sp"    
 android:padding="5dp"
/>

Comment: OK, but you don't define that namespace in the resources file.  I'm not familiar with the way you're trying to refer to device_name, but from an XML parser point of view, that is why the XML you're providing is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong opening tag for `<resources>`. Change `<resources>` to 
`<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2>` and then use the regular closing tag

Answer (score 1):

The third one under BluetoothChat has 'Error:' written next to it.  Is that what's causing the error, or did you add that to show which line was causing the error?

Comment: I included that in the question

Answer (score 1):

You need `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` before the resources tag