# Rotation of an Image on touch

Tags: android

I am developing a simple application. I have an image(for e.g a wheel) on image view. I want to turn the image according to my finger moves(like rotating the wheel by hand) and stops it when i release the touch. I just rotate the image with simple animation without touching the screen.  Kindly provide me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://go-lambda.blogspot.in/2012/02/rotary-knob-widget-on-android.html).

You will have to create a custom view and handle the `onTouch` events to calculate rotation angle.

In `onDraw` method

1. Save the  `canvas`  state.
2. Rotate the canvas using `Camera` class.
3. Draw the image on the `canvas`.
4. Restore the `canvas`

Comment: thanks buddy.saw the link. but using that when i creating the xml i get the error: error parsing xml: unbound prefix.  <TouchRoate.Android.RotaryKnobView 
    android:id="@+id/jogView"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    Android:layout_gravity="center"
  />

Comment: check if you have defined `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

for more help [visit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix)