# Custom SwipeRefreshLayout in Android

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

How can I inflate a custom layout when I pull for refresh? My code is here: a layout which exist a loader and below that is a TextView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    shareImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shareImg);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/HelveticaNeueLT.otf");
    homeHeaderTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeHeaderTxt);
    homeHeaderTxt.setTypeface(tf);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    loadDashBoard();

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadDashBoard();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

            }, 5000);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So... What is the problem?

Comment: I dont have any idea how can I inflate an Layout inside it..

Comment: By default its shoeing circle rotation but i want to open a View with blue header and having a  Loader and textview

Comment: I don't believe you can change the loading animation of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. If you want to change it, I think you have to rebuilt the `SwipeRefreshLayout` by yourself

Comment: Please take a look here: [Pull to refresh ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257009/android-pulltorefesh-library-customize-loading-pulling-refreshing-image)