# How to fix parsing XML: unbound prefix in android

Tags: android, xml, prefix

I am getting an XML:Unbound prefix error in android  i tried a lot but it was still occurring please make it solve as soon as possible..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click" />

    <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
        android:id="@+id/gauge3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:endValue="100"
        app:pointEndColor="@color/Green"
        app:pointStartColor="@color/Red"
        app:startAngel="180"
        app:startValue="0"
        app:strokeCap="BUTT"
        app:strokeColor="@color/Gray"
        app:strokeWidth="20dp"
        app:sweepAngel="180" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [frequent problem in android view, Error parsing XML: unbound prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: It is showing--> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'endValue' in package 'com.example.demo2c1testpanel'

Comment: yes it was showing error in xml dude this is the error------->>>>>> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'endValue' in package 'com.example.demo2c1testpanel'

Comment: Hay I change according to ans but I still get error "Error:(43, 32) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'rangeColors' with value '@array/rangeColors1')."

Comment: check whether the rangeColors1 exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Again it was showing error called error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'endValue' in package 'com.example.demo2c1testpanel'

Comment: This is another question, I have solved your first one, please ask it in a new question

Comment: i asked it in this link please make it solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685315/fix-error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-endvalue-in-package