# How to fix error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml

I am writing an application that consists of the Library downloaded from [here](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/archive/master.zip) and i am getting an error called "**Error parsing XML:Unbound prefix**" how to fix this error and this is my XML please make it solve

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
          <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="#1E88E5"
                    android:text="Button" />
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Float Button" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#1E88E5" />



    </RelativeLayout>
        </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView>
  <!-- Error Occurred Here -->         <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:background="#1E88E5"
                    materialdesign:animate="true"
                    materialdesign:iconDrawable="@drawable/pencil" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2221386/646806

Comment: I already did this tricks dude but didn't work  @RobinHood

Comment: add this xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" & trying to use Linear Layout & Restart your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should replace

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

with

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Source: [the demo project included in the link you provided in your question](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Thanks dude it works fine by placing xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   @iRuth

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in you parent Relative Layout

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`