# Error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in XML

Tags: android

I am trying to use a cardview in my project, but while I am creating my XML file for my cardview, I keep getting the error

> error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

but if I take out my cardview widget, it works. I looked at other questions and tried their responses but it isn't working. Does anyone see what is wrong with my code?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="8dp"
         card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp" >
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are missing a prefix for  `card_view`.

Comment: Just missed that. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp" >
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you should add `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` this for your parent layout

Comment: it need not be for the parent layout you can have the namespace defined for cardview also

Comment: if u add it to the parent then u don't have to repeat with all views you adding.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

You are missing the prefix for `card_view`.

This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices.

You could also do

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```