# error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix TableLayout

Tags: android, xml

Hello i'm new in Android Programming
Currently i'm practicing TableLayout but somehow there's an strange error.

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#004400"
>
```

Need help for find the error

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unbound prefix" error here:

> ```
> andorid:gravity="Center"
> ```

you have a typo with `andorid`.

For the follow-up problem: You can only have only one root-level element in a XML file. Don't self-close your initial `TableLayout` with the `/>` at the end but keep it open with `>`, and close with `</TableLayout>` at the end, with nothing following it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line from:

```
>
```

to

```
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this two line in your main layout:-
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

[frequent issues arising in android view, Error parsing XML: unbound prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix)