# How can I solved this issue in my layout: “error: Error parsing XML:unbound prefix

Tags: android

this is the xml file of tab layout in which define toolbar,viepage
so how fix this error.i dont know how to fix it please help me or suggest me where am doing wrong Probably is something very simple, but I am stucked. Any idea?please heplp

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:padding="2dp"
            app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.tutorialsbuzz.slidingtabdemo.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share full layout code

Answer (score 0):

You need add `xmlns` attribute to your root element. Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.tutorialsbuzz.slidingtabdemo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
and check if  you have tabstrip.java file in your pakage. which is required for it to work properly

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <com.example.SlidingTabLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tab">  
            </com.example.SlidingTabLayout>


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: with linearlayout it's working.Vasily Kabunov ur suggestion is no working

Comment: okay then use linearlayout . but just make sure that u have tabstrip.java

Answer (score 0):

You might need to follow this,

You need to add some **content to parent node or issue with namespace**

First node needs to add : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Check this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221386/2826147).

Hope this helps.