# Error parsing XML: Prefix must not be bound to reserved namespace explicitly

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I cannot fix this error even after trying the mentioned techniques in other posts. I don't have crashlytics in my application. It's rather simple.
The issue persists even after cleaning the build and invalidating caches.
The following code is present in the values.xml file with a curly red line under the resources keyword.

```
    <resources
    xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
  ...
```

I know this question was asked a few times but I'm not able to fix the error in my application.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error messages? What reserved namespace is it? xml is a reserved namespace..

Comment: The error says that the prefix 'xmlns' cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for 'xmlns' be bound to any prefix explicitly.

Comment: are you having an element with xmlns as its prefix?

Comment: did you find any solution.

Comment: Yes @krishna5688.

Comment: @AlphaQ I am also facing the same issue, please give me solution if you have.

Comment: @Shailesh Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-issues-arising-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix

Comment: @AlphaQ Thank you for your reply, I'll try with that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of ns3 is invalid because the namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` is reserved.

See section 3 of the XML Namespaces 1.1 specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/

> The prefix xmlns is used only to declare namespace bindings and is by
>   definition bound to the namespace name http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/.
>   It must not be declared or undeclared. Other prefixes must not be
>   bound to this namespace name, and it must not be declared as the
>   default namespace. Element names must not have the prefix xmlns.